# bash shell script jq Get a field and make statistics

Tags: json, bash, shell, count, jq

I want to count the number of "domains" for which "adminLock" is equal to 1.

This is my json data structure:

```
{
  "code": 0,
  "message": "成功",
  "data": {
    "recordCount": "128",
    "pageSize": 100,
    "page": 1,
    "pageCount": 2,
    "data": [
      {
        "domainsID": "173652434",
        "nsGroupID": "199",
        "groupID": "78987",
        "domains": "dome1.com",
        "state": 3,
        "userLock": 0,
        "adminLock": 0,
        "view_type": "1"
      },
      {
        "domainsID": "173205836",
        "nsGroupID": "199",
        "groupID": "78987",
        "domains": "dome2.com",
        "state": 3,
        "userLock": 0,
        "adminLock": 1,
        "view_type": "1"
      },
      {
        "domainsID": "173205812",
        "nsGroupID": "199",
        "groupID": "78987",
        "domains": "dome3.com",
        "state": 3,
        "userLock": 0,
        "adminLock": 0,
        "view_type": "1"
      },
      {
        "domainsID": "173203610",
        "nsGroupID": "199",
        "groupID": "78987",
        "domains": "dome4.com",
        "state": 3,
        "userLock": 0,
        "adminLock": 1,
        "view_type": "1"
      },
      {
        "domainsID": "173203210",
        "nsGroupID": "199",
        "groupID": "78987",
        "domains": "dome5.com",
        "state": 3,
        "userLock": 0,
        "adminLock": 1,
        "view_type": "1"
      },
      {
        "domainsID": "173203131",
        "nsGroupID": "199",
        "groupID": "78987",
        "domains": "dome6.com",
        "state": 3,
        "userLock": 0,
        "adminLock": 1,
        "view_type": "1"
      },
      {
        "domainsID": "173203074",
        "nsGroupID": "199",
        "groupID": "78987",
        "domains": "dome7.com",
        "state": 3,
        "userLock": 0,
        "adminLock": 1,
        "view_type": "1"
      }
    ],
    "nextPage": 2
  }
}
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
'.data.data[] | select(.adminLock == 1) | .domains'
```

I can get the value of .domains, but how can I count how many times it occurs?

## Replenish

The script I am using is the bash shell
This command gets the value, I want to count the domains value in the case of adminLock=1, and count the number of domains
————————
Judging that adminLock=1 is getting the domains value, and counting how many in total

Answer (score 1):

To have a single count of all resulting items, either make an array and determine its `length`:

```bash
.data.data | map(select(.adminLock == 1)) | length
```

```json
5
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4fbKGzpq7DL)

Or iterate and count, e.g. using `reduce`:

```bash
reduce (.data.data[] | select(.adminLock == 1)) as $i (0; .+1)
```

```json
5
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/gb0wrF7JLVC)

The first approach may seem more "natural" but it actually builds up an array that you eventually may not need. Therefore, if you only need the count, not the items themselves, use the second approach.

---

To count the items based on a certain property, say, the distinct values of `.domains`, create an according structure and count as shown before. The array approach could group the items using `group_by`:

```bash
.data.data | map(select(.adminLock == 1)) | group_by(.domains)
| map("\(first.domains): \(length)") # create your desired format
```

```json
[
  "dome2.com: 1",
  "dome4.com: 1",
  "dome5.com: 1",
  "dome6.com: 1",
  "dome7.com: 1"
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/EZhF3ndkm8P)

The iterative approach successively builds up your output structure, e.g. an object with the property as field names:

```bash
reduce (.data.data[] | select(.adminLock == 1)) as $i (
  {}; .[$i.domains] += 1 # create your desired format
)
```

```json
{
  "dome2.com": 1,
  "dome4.com": 1,
  "dome5.com": 1,
  "dome6.com": 1,
  "dome7.com": 1
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/p_ATbzwRqT9)

Comment: I use the bash shell language

'.data.data[] | select(.adminLock == 1) | .domains' 

Use this command to get the value, I want to count the domains value in the case of adminLock=1, and count how many

Comment: @study Do you mean one count per domain name? To clarify, you could include in your question the expected output for your sample input.

Comment: Yes, because I have already used adminLock=1 as a judgment. If it is adminLock=1, I will get the value of domains. After the acquisition is successful, because there are many such data in the json data, I will count how many such data appear.

Answer (score 0):

In general, rather than constructing an array, it's better to use a stream-oriented counting method:

```
def count(s): reduce s as $x (0;.+1);
```

In your case, it seems you could get away with:

```
count(.data.data[] | select(.adminLock == 1))
```

but perhaps you would want to check there is a `domains` key:

```
count(.data.data[] | select(.adminLock == 1 and has("domains") ))
```

If, however, you want to count the number of **distinct** domains satisfying the condition, it would probably be simplest to use `unique`:

```
[.data.data[] | select(.adminLock == 1) | .domains] | unique | length
```

But it's not hard to write a stream-oriented version of `unique` to avoid having to call `unique/0` ...

Comment: I use the bash shell language

```'.data.data[] | select(.adminLock == 1) | .domains' ```

Use this command to get the value, I want to count the domains value in the case of adminLock=1, and count how many